# Android send user to email client chooser

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am trying to redirect user to check his email via available email clients. Currently what I have achieved is to send the user directly to Gmail client. Below there are some  functions that I use to generate implicit intent:

```
fun attept1(): Intent {
    val intent = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(
        Intent.ACTION_MAIN, 
        Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL
    )
    intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    return intent
}

fun attempt2(): Intent {
    val intent = Intent(ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.type = "message/rfc822"
    intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    return intent
}

//... somewhere in the code

val emailIntent = attempt1() //or attempt2()

startActivity(emailIntent)
```

With **attempt 1** I am successfully redirecting the user to Gmail but I do have at least 5 email clients installed (BlueMail, Outlook, Yahoo Mail, Email, Temp Mail). They're ignored completely.

With **attempt 2**, at first it was showing unrelated apps like Slack, but after I have installed other email clients it just shows a toast message: `Can't open this file`. I have tried with `Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose client: ")` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Attempt 2 is singularly awful. Have you tried `Intent.createChooser()` with the code from attempt 1? That is the right idea, so I'm wondering if Gmail wound up registered as a default handler for that `Intent` structure on your test device.

Comment: I did - no luck. They're both awful, they don't work.

Comment: Well, there is no requirement that an email app advertise that it is an email app for the purposes of what you're trying to do. I am somewhat surprised that Outlook does not do so, though.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll have to search for all email providers through package manager. I can't see an quicker way out of this.